# Tangent bundle $TM$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a submanifod of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Show that the tangent bundle $TM$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

ps.:I'm trying to use charts, but I'm slowing down, because I've been studying this for a long time.

Comment: "Charts" is probably the word you are looking for, not "cards".

Comment: If you saying you are using *cards* instead of *charts*, people might think you are using [Tarots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarot) to guess the correct answer. :-) (just kidding)

Comment: I edited it to fix that one :). On the other hand, there is a proof at the bottom of page [2 here](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~yakov/Geometry/3.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in M$ and $(U,\phi)$ be a chart of $M$ around $x$, then let us define $TU\subset TM$ and $T\varphi\colon TU\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ by:
$$TU=\{(x,v):x\in U,v\in T_xM\},T\varphi(x,v)=(\varphi(x),\mathrm{d}_x\varphi(v)),$$
then $\{(TU,T\varphi)\}$ is an atlas for $TM$.

Answer (score 1):

Given a local parametrization $h:U \to V \subseteq M \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, we set $h(u)=x$. Then a vector $v \in \mathbb R^n$ is tangent to $M$ at $x$ if and only if it is a linear combination of vectors $\frac{\partial h}{\partial u_i}(u)$ for $a \leq i \leq n$.

Implicitly, this is a subspace of $TM  \subset M \times \mathbb R^n$.

Hence, as a subset of $\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n$. Since $h$ was smooth, its derivative is smooth and gives local co-ordinates to the second co-ordinate by taking the appropriate linear combinations (total derivative.)