# The tangent bundle of the 2-sphere $TS^2$ is an embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R^6}$

Tags: differential-geometry

Define the tangent bundle of $S^2$ as:
$$TS^2 = \{(u,v)\ |\ u,v \in \mathbb{R}^3, |u| = 1, \left<u,v\right> = 0\}$$
I want to show that this is an embedded sub-manifold of $\mathbb{R}^6$.

My intuition leads me to say this will be a 4-manifold, but the proof that it is an embedded sub-manifold is leaving me stumped.

Edit: I noticed here: [Tangent bundle $TM$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762530/tangent-bundle-tm-is-a-submanifold-of-mathbbr2n)

How do I extend this to also give embedding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f((u_1,u_2,u_3),(v_1,v_2,v_3)) = (u_1,u_2,u_3,v_1,v_2,v_3)$$